# Renaming node (or nodelet) in roslaunch for top

Tags: roslaunch, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some pretty nodelet heavy roslaunch files.

I'd like their 'command' in top to be more descriptive than just 'nodelet'.

Is there a way to rename the execution command so that linux will report its CPU usage with a custom name?  It can get pretty bad when there's 12+ nodelets.  :)

```
PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                             
3634 chad       20   0  164m  18m  10m S   46  0.5   3:58.35 nodelet                                                                             
3618 chad       20   0  163m  18m  10m S    8  0.5   1:32.81 nodelet                                                                             
3592 chad       20   0  215m  32m  12m S    5  0.8   0:41.08 nodelet                                                                             
3574 chad       20   0 37860 9896 2920 S    1  0.2   0:02.60 python
```

I do have a workaround with 'htop'  as it displays the entire command including launch args, but that's clunkier and not installed by default.

---

Although, it's not really relevant to my problem, here's an [example launch file](http://github.com/cwru-robotics/smart_wheelchair/blob/master/otto_sensors/launch/filters_kinect.launch).  The real issue is that top reports the executable name as compiled, but for nodelets, it's always 'nodelet'.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11371/renaming-node-(or-nodelet)-in-roslaunch-for-top/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-09-29**:
I've edited to include an example launch file that contains many nodelets.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-29**:
Could you post an example launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try "top -c". I think that will at least replace htop.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2